# Escaping variables in Email templates

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, apex-variable

I am trying to build the body of an email by using the fields of a given custom object(SObject). On this given SObject I am including some variables. One of those variables is the title of the Contact. Escaping variables does not work, I can see the plain text, not the escaped characters.

The code:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test (Translating)" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="StaticMessage__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
    <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.MainMessageTop__c}" escape="false"/>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Field value of MainMessageTop__c is:

```
Your title is {!$recipient.Title}
```

Result:

```
Your title is {!$recipient.Title}
```

Expected result:

```
Your title is CEO
```

Comment: I don't think "`escape="false"` dynamically change field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two possible workarounds.

1. Have a numbered list of possible parameters:
   0 -> $recipient.title
   1 -> $recipient.email
   2 -> ...

and then having a field value of

```
Your title is {0}
```

and in the template something like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.MainMessageTop__c}" escape="false">
    <apex:param value="{!recipient.title}"/>
    <apex:param value="{!recipient.email}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</apex:outputText>
```

2. or have a list of pre-defined possible attributes, and have a huge replace as value of the outputText.

that will allow you to have a field value like

```
Your title is {$recipient.Title}
```

but the template gets something like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(relatedTo.MainMessageTop__c,
    '{$recipient.Title}',$recipient.Title),
    '{$recipient.Email}',$recipient.Email)}"/>
```

I hope it helps ;)